# Why List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>() ;is wrong?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

why the following code is wrong in Java?

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

I know `List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>()` is correct.

Comment: (The duplicate is actually simpler, because it's not "doubly generic" like this one is - but if you understand that, you can apply it to this easily. Basically, consider what `list.add(new LinkedList<Integer>())` is doing to an object which was created as (and may still be *referenced* as) `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`.)

Comment: This has been asked several times in the past.  In fact, @JonSkeet has answered it more than once.  His answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265) is, in my opinion, better than his answer in the one that he closed this as a duplicate of, despite how much I _loathe_ having `Dog extends Animal` as an example in any question about inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Because generic types in Java are not covariant.

Comment: could you give me more explain? where related to the covariant?

Comment: It was marked as duplicate, please follow the linked questions.